# Replacing values in a column with a max value relative to another column's value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a predicative model that predicts the value of an item from the starting bid. The output dataframe has an item type, item origin, starting bid for an item, and the actual value of item.

Note : The starting bid is always fixed in increments of 100, and no two items with same ItemType/ItemOrigin will have the same Starting Bid.

| Row | ItemType | ItemOrigin | Starting Bid ($) | Value of item ($) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Antique | USA | 1000 | 2000 |
| 2 | Antique | USA | 1100 | 2200 |
| 3 | Clothing | UK | 600 | 1000 |
| 4 | Clothing | UK | 700 | 800 |
| 5 | Clothing | UK | 800 | 1100 |
| 6 | Clothing | UK | 900 | 500 |
| 7 | Clothing | UK | 1000 | 600 |

The assumption is that when an item of same `ItemType` and `ItemOrigin` has a higher starting bid, the value of item is equal or greater to an item with a lower starting bid.

Therefore, the 4th row doesn't make sense because the value of item in row 4 is lower than row 3, yet the starting bid is higher. Same for row 6, relative to row 5.

So I want to clean the output data so that only the 4th and 6th row would change:

| Row | ItemType | ItemOrigin | Starting Bid ($) | Value of item ($) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Antique | USA | 1000 | 2000 |
| 2 | Antique | USA | 1100 | 2200 |
| 3 | Clothing | UK | 600 | 1000 |
| **4** | **Clothing** | **UK** | **700** | **1000** |
| 5 | Clothing | UK | 800 | 1100 |
| **6** | **Clothing** | **UK** | **900** | **1100** |
| **7** | **Clothing** | **UK** | **1000** | **1100** |

Basically, I want to take the max `Value of item ($)` of each ItemType and ItemOrigin from the starting bid, and replace any lower Values with the max value.

I know the best way of doing this is WHILE applying my model and keeping the current max in a for loop. However, the way I am applying my model is not through a for loop but instead through multiprocessing `starmap` so I don't think it will work. So I'm trying to do this after the fact.

I started with doing a groupby to get the max, but this shows the overall max and I don't want to replace based on the global max, but instead by the max **relative to the previous starting bids.**

```
d = {
  'ItemType': ['Antique', 'Antique', 'Clothing', 'Clothing', 'Clothing', 'Clothing', 'Clothing'],
  'Item Origin': ['USA', 'USA', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK'],
  'Starting Bid': [1000, 1100, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000],
  'Value of item': [2000, 2200, 1000, 800, 1100, 500, 600]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
max_val = df.groupby(['ItemType', 'Item Origin']).agg({'Value of item' : 'max'}).reset_index()
print(max_val)
```

Output:

```
   ItemType Item Origin  Value of item
0   Antique         USA           2200
1  Clothing          UK           1100
```

EDIT: I have added another row 7 in my example to illustrate that I want the value of item to be replaced for all future rows, not limited to just the next immediate row.

Answer (score 1):

With [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) window calculation:

```
df['Value of item'] = (df.groupby(['ItemType', 'Item Origin'], sort=False)
                       ['Value of item'].rolling(2, min_periods=1, closed='both')
                       .max().values)
```

---

```
   ItemType Item Origin  Starting Bid  Value of item
0   Antique         USA          1000         2000.0
1   Antique         USA          1100         2200.0
2  Clothing          UK           600         1000.0
3  Clothing          UK           700         1000.0
4  Clothing          UK           800         1100.0
5  Clothing          UK           900         1100.0
6  Clothing          UK          1000         1100.0
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for the case I provided, but if there is a 6th row with `Clothing, UK, 1000, 600` it will not change the 600 to 1100.

Comment: The update doesn't work if yet another row is added... However I used your solution but changed the first parameter of the 'rolling' function to the number of rows of my dataframe and it works for my usage. Thank you.

Comment: @codenoodles, I've extended your initial df with additional rows and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I think this works as you expect:

```
for _, group in df.copy().groupby(['ItemType', 'Item Origin']):
    # Check if Value of item is correct (sorted)
    if np.all(group['Value of item'].values[:-1] <= group['Value of item'][1:]):
        continue
    df.loc[group.index, 'Value of item'] = np.where(
        group['Value of item'] > group['Value of item'].shift(fill_value=0),
        group['Value of item'],
        group['Value of item'].shift(fill_value=0)
    )
```

Basically we iterate over all the `[ItemType, Item Origin]` groups and check if the values are sorted. If not, we reemplace the values with the previous maximum value of the group.

Comment: Thank you, this works for the case I provided, but if there is a 6th row with `Clothing, UK, 1000, 600` it will not change the 600 to 1100.

Answer (score 0):

use this code should work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {
  'ItemType': ['Antique', 'Antique', 'Clothing', 'Clothing', 'Clothing', 'Clothing'],
  'Item Origin': ['USA', 'USA', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK'],
  'Starting Bid': [1000, 1100, 600, 700, 800, 900],
  'Value of item': [2000, 2200, 1000, 800, 1100, 500]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
df = df.sort_values(by=['ItemType', 'Item Origin', 'Starting Bid'])
# df['Starting Bid']  = df['Starting Bid'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
IIG = df['ItemType'] + df['Item Origin'] # + df['Starting Bid']
IIG = IIG.to_numpy()
IIG = np.expand_dims(IIG, -1)
arr = df.to_numpy()
arr = np.concatenate([IIG, arr[:, 2:]], axis = 1)
k0 = arr[1:, 0] == arr[:-1, 0]
k2 = arr[1:, 2] < arr[:-1, 2]
fin = k0 & k2

foh = np.concatenate([[False], fin], axis = 0)
alt = np.concatenate([fin, [False]], axis = 0)
arr[foh, 2] = arr[alt, 2]
df['Value of item'] = arr[:, 2]
df
```

the result
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works for the case I provided, but if there is a another row with Clothing, UK, 1000, 600 it will not change the 600 to 1100. I have updated my question to take this case into account.

Comment: for loop is a good solution.